# x264 fails to build using MacPorts

Tags: ffmpeg, macports, x264

Using MacPorts to install FFmpeg, I ran into an error with the dependency x264:

```
...
--->  Computing dependencies for ffmpeg
--->  Dependencies to be installed: x264
--->  Configuring x264
Error: Failed to configure x264, consult /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_multimedia_x264/x264/work/x264-956c8d8/config.log
Error: org.macports.configure for port x264 returned: configure failure: command execution failed
Error: Failed to install x264
...
```

...which persists even after updating and upgrading everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

..and to answer my own problem with a functional (but probably not recommended) hack, I consulted the `config.log` as suggested by the error message above. The problem, according to the log, was that clang does not support the `-falign-loops` option. x264 built successfully after commenting out the two configuration lines that contained "falign-loops". The configuration file was found here:

```
/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_multimedia_x264/x264/work/x264-956c8d8/configure
```

After commenting out the two problematic lines, `port install x264` worked perfectly.